# Target input fields in Javascript that don't have a class or ID

Tags: javascript

I need to target a submit button that doesn't either have a class or an ID. I am unable to add either of both to that submit button. This would be a simple task for me if I used jQuery, but I need this in pure JS - which I'm not very proficient at.

So how would I target something (in this case a submit button) without a class or ID in pure Javascript?

The selector in jQuery would look like this: `$('input[type="submit"]:last')`.

Comment: Show us what the selector would look like in jQuery, and we'll show you what it would look like without jQuery ?

Comment: Added an example selector in JQuery.

Comment: And I added an answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery selector

```
$('input[type="submit"]:last')
```

equates to something like this

```
var all  = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]');
var last = all[all.length - 1];
```

or a one-liner

```
var elem = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]')).pop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you add a `name` attribute to the tag? If so, you can use `document.getElementsByName()`. Otherwise, you can get the position of the element on the page relative to elements with the same tag and use `document.getElementsByTagName()`.

Comment: Since the OP cannot add either class or ID, it's a safe bet he cannot add name either. But more generally, I'm confused by the frequent use of name I see in recent posts. I understand it is a way to tie together radio buttons that form a group, and that it can define anchor locations, but other than that, what use is it?